# how to keep the div from overflowing on col-md-12? (bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Want to keep the image and div below at the same width.

Works fine until I get to around 545px to 575px window size.  The .header changes width proportion only at col-md-12.  Is there a way to keep the same aspect ratio?

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANY34.jpg)

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/jggrs/pen/ayoveb)

HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="first-column col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/500">
      <div class="header">header</div>
     </div>

     <div class="second-column col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/500">
        <div class="header">header</div>
    </div>

    <div class="third-column col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/500">
       <div class="header">header</div>
    </div>

<!--END ROW-->
</div> 

<!--END CONTAINER-->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.first-column{background-color: #c0c0c0}
.second-column{background-color: #808080}
.third-column{background-color: #778899}


.header{
background-color:rgba(45,44,89,0.7);
width: 100%;
color: #ffffff;
position: relative;
bottom: 40px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The image is not wide enough. Try `<img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/540">`

Comment: The problem is that image is not wide enough. You can change your image as background, and take background-attchment:cover, so you can stretch and it adapt.. is not perfect but is a possible solution..

Comment: It worked... Thanks guys.  https://codepen.io/jggrs/pen/QMLyYX

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap `.img-responsive` class has a `max-width:100%;` but it doesn't set the width. 
So add a width to the class.

```
.img-responsive {
  width: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/rickydam/pen/XarXYX